# Gradle build / test failed - kryo.KryoException: Buffer overflow

Tags: exception, testing, gradle, buffer, kryo

While running a Gradle build, tests are failing.

PS: 
1. Gradle is using the correct JDK (1.6) to build. 
2. I tried this with JDK 1.7, same error comes there as well. 
3. I don't see this error when I build it locally (with JDK 1.6) on a linux/windows
4. machine but one of the machine is giving me this error.

**My ?s**
1. What can be done to fix the com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer overflow error.
2. Why Gradle process failed, even when test section in build.gradle says:

```
   test {

        ignoreFailures=true
        //more code here for test section...
        //..
   }
```

Any hints/help appreciated. Error snapshot is shown below:

```
:test
Unexpected exception thrown.
org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53371'.
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:88)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionReceive.run(MessageHub.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:162)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readByte(Input.java:255)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:64)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:53)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:83)
        ... 5 more
> Building > :test > 84 tests completed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Process 'Gradle Worker 6' finished with non-zero exit value 139

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an internal error. Best chance is to try with the latest Gradle version.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I'll try a recent/latest Gradle version. Any idea, if this issue is system specific (I saw some blogs saying it can be fixed if I use a different JDK 1.x version). I tried it, didn't resolve the issue. I have Gradle 1.6 in all machine (local windows and other linux/unix).. this issue is not coming in any of the Windows local machines (either mine or any developer) and nor in any Linux machines. There are couple of machines (Linux) where I'm getting this error. Do you think, this error can be due to some "test" which is taking a lot of time or hanging for some strange reason?

Comment: All I know is that this used to be a limitation/bug of Gradle's `Test` task. As of 2.1, it should be completely, or at least mostly, fixed.